# derby busqueda por fecha join

Tags: sql, derby

debo seleccionar los nombre de los clientes cuyo servicio se hizo en 2012-07-15

```
SELECT nombre FROM Clientes c JOIN Servicios s WHERE s.Fecha = '2012-07-15';
```

pero me da error

> [Exception, Error code 30.000, SQLState 42X01] Error de sintaxis: Encountered "WHERE" at line 1, column 48.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta la condición de join usando la cláusula `ON`. No tengo los detalles de tus columnas, pero tal vez tengas una columna `ClientId` en ambas tablas, o algo por el estilo. En ese caso, la consulta sería algo como:

```
select nombre
  from Clientes c
  join Servicios s
    on s.ClientId = c.ClientId -- te falta esto
 where s,Fecha = '2012-07-15';
```